# Which version of xcode supports "Swift programming language"?

Tags: xcode, swift

Apple introduced a new programming language for iOS 8 / OS X. Which version of xcode supports Swift?

I am trying on Xcode 5.1, but it is not supported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swift programming language was introduced in Xcode 6 beta version.

Xcode 6 has deep support for Swift throughout. It’s easy to create a brand new app using 100% Swift code, add new Swift code or frameworks to existing apps, and view documentation in either Swift, Objective-C, or both. All the popular affordances such as “Jump to Definition” or “Open Quickly” work equally well with Swift, and even Objective-C header definitions can be shown in Swift syntax.

Please refer the following links for more detail:

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11
- https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Answer (score 2):

It’s Xcode 6+. And you have to save the Swift code in a `.swift` file, not `.m`.

Answer (score 0):

You need xcode 6.1 Minimum for osx apps. If you try to use the orginial version of xcode 6, you will only be able to use the playground and create osx apps.